# Sending email to multiple recipients

Tags: perl, email, smtp, multipart

I've moved some old code from an old unix box to our new unix box, and I'm having some difficulty with a perl script sending email to multiple recipients. It works on the old box.

Old box perl: version 5.004_04 built for PA-RISC2.0

New box perl: v5.8.8 built for IA64.ARCHREV_0-thread-multi-LP64

Here's the basics of the script (stripped-down):

```
use Net::SMTP::Multipart;
$to = "sam\@bogus.com tom\@foo.com";
$smtp = Net::SMTP::Multipart->new($smtpserver);
$smtp->Header(To    =>  $to,
      From  =>  "junk\@junk.com",
      Subj  =>  "This is a test.");
$smtp->Text("Hello, world!\n");
$smtp->End();
```

This works if I change it to `$to = "justOneEmail\@address.com"`, but if I have two or more email addresses (separated by spaces), it no longer works. I don't get an error message, but no message shows up.

Any ideas why?

Comment: You have a _new_ Unix box that has a six year old version of Perl? Interesting definition of new! But I suppose it's an improvement on the almost fifteen year old version you have before :-)

Comment: @Dave, lol. Yep. "New" is relative. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it [like this](http://search.cpan.org/~orien/Net-SMTP-Multipart-1.5.4/Multipart.pm#EXAMPLES):

```
use Net::SMTP::Multipart;
$to1 = "sam\@bogus.com"; 
$to2 = 'tom@foo.com';
$smtp = Net::SMTP::Multipart->new($smtpserver);
$smtp->Header(To    =>  [ $to1, $to2, 'another_email@server.com' ],
              From  =>  "junk\@junk.com",
              Subj  =>  "This is a test.");
$smtp->Text("Hello, world!\n");
$smtp->End();
```

Notice that if you use double-quotes, you should escape the @ in the email addresses, or perl may try to interpret it as an array interpolation.

Comment: So the `To` under `Header` is not the place to put the email addresses? The examples on CPAN don't show the attribute you're using: http://search.cpan.org/~orien/Net-SMTP-Multipart-1.5.4/Multipart.pm

Comment: OK, my bad, i assumed you were using Net::SMTP, but you're using Net::SMTP::Multipart. I think your problem is you need a list of addresses, that is, each address is a string, separate these strings with commas. For good measure, just do it the way they do the "CC" in the CPAN example in the link you mentioned. Editing my answer to reflect this.

Comment: OK. Newbie question: if I have `@tolist=['a@b.com','x@z.com'];` how do I convey that to the Header? Like this? `To => @tolist`? Won't that mess up the parm list?

Comment: @JonathanM, you will want to write `@tolist=('a@b.com','x@z.com');` and pass it in as `To => \@tolist` **OR** `$tolist=['a@b.com','x@z.com'];` and pass it in as `To => $tolist`.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu, thanks. Can you tell me what the difference is between the `()` notation and the `[]` notation?

Comment: () creates a "list", which is more or less the same as an array.
@varname is an array variable.
$varname is an scalar variable (non-array, single value).
\@array or [ x, y, z ] creates a *reference* to an array (more or less like a pointer to an array, in C). 
So you can do $scalar = \@array ,  or $scalar = [x, y, z]   -   see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html

Comment: @theglauber, Whoops! I tried this. `@tolist=('a@b.com','x@z.com');` and then `To => \@tolist,`. But it says `Cant' coerce array into hash at.../Net/SMTP.pm line 364.` If I leave off the backslash, it messes up the parameter list. I'd do it with square brackets, but in practice, the list has been handed to me in a variable.

Comment: The literal `To => ['a@b.com','x@z.com'],` gets the same error about coercing an array.

Comment: Looks like the documentation for the Net::SMTP::Multipart module is wrong. I installed the module (v 1.6) on my Strawberry Perl 5.12, and wasn't able to make it work at all. Even the example in the documentation doesn't work. Sorry. You may have to contact the module's writer.

Comment: Thanks. Your detective work encouraged me to move to Mail::Sender.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of separating the email addresses  with spaces, use a comma with no intervening spaces.  This works for me..

Comment: Could you provide code as an example of what you are doing?

Answer (score -3):

Declare an array and put all the email id's like

```
@MailTo = ('mail1@demomail.com', 'mail2@demomail.com', ...., 'mailn@demomail.com')
```

Now use the `Net::SMTP` module to send out the emails

```
$smtp->to(@MailTo);
```