# Sending email to multiple recipients with arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, email, html-email

This is a follow up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521011/sending-email-to-multiple-recipients). The solution is clear but not applicable in every case. For example, I have an array with with recipients whose number can vary with time. Hence I use a file as an input and also an array to store all recipients email address.

I have tried the following but this does not work.

```
use Email::MIME::CreateHTML;
my $email = Email::MIME->create_html(
        header => [
                From => $from,
                To => \@email_to,  #email_to contains a@abc.com, b@abc.com, c@abc.com etc
                Subject => "$status_value Sim Issues",
        ],
        body => $body_of_message,
        text_body => $body_of_message
);
```

Comment: What is `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@email_to`? If `[ $to1, $to2, 'another_email@server.com' ]` works as expected then `\@email_to` should also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving comma separated list of recipients email address

```
...
To => join (',', @email_to),    # should be a string : 'a@abc.com, b@abc.com, c@abc.com'
...
```

Comment: Isn't it `join` instead of `split`?

Comment: @M42 Oops, blunder in a hurry. thanks for pointing it out. corrected.

Comment: Could you please point out where in the docs is this written or how you arrived at the solution?
Also if possible can you say why is the code in question(the one I posted) not working.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam as pointed out in a comment in solution, value to `To => ` should be a comma separated string. Whereas you are supplying *array reference* `\@email_to`.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam talking about documentation, I've used [`MIME::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm) where they demonstrate cc list as comma separated value. I thought it would apply same to the module you're using, if in case that works for you.